# How do i remove this table column?

Tags: html

Here's the code:

```
`% # First declare that output from this template is to be put inside another template after running all the code (rendering)
% rebase(skinning + '_skin.tpl', title=page_title)     # (See note above)
% # From here, concentrate on the content we would like to show:
<!-- Lines not starting with % are standard HTML. This HTML code is defined in views/all_items.tpl -->
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">No.</th>
        % for k in displaykeys:
        <th scope="col">{{k.title()}}</th>
        % end   # Usual python indention to structure code does not work in .tpl files - "end" is used instead to end a block
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      % for i, d in enumerate(displaydata):    # displaydata is expected to be a list of dictionaries
      % link_url = "/events/" + str(i + 1)     # relative url to detailed view
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>
        % for k in displaykeys:     # Go thru the keys in the same order as for the headline row
        <td><a href="{{link_url}}" alt="See details">{{displaydata[i][k]}}</a></td>
        % end   # Usual python indention to structure code does not work in .tpl files - "end" is used instead to end a block
      </tr>
      % end
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>`
```

Here is the output in picture 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUYDx.jpg
I just want to remove the "No." column with the index number..
What do i have to do spcifically in order to do that?

Comment: maybe it is easier to read the code here: https://pastebin.com/6W542FRF

Comment: removethese two lines: <th scope="col">No.</th> and <th scope="row">{{i + 1}}</th>

Comment: I'm guessing your using some kind of templating engine or something, what's with all the `%`?

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Delete the two rows with th tag.

```
<!-- Lines not starting with % are standard HTML. This HTML code is defined in views/all_items.tpl -->
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        % for k in displaykeys:
        <th scope="col">{{k.title()}}</th>
        % end   # Usual python indention to structure code does not work in .tpl files - "end" is used instead to end a block
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      % for i, d in enumerate(displaydata):    # displaydata is expected to be a list of dictionaries
      % link_url = "/events/" + str(i + 1)     # relative url to detailed view
      <tr>
        % for k in displaykeys:     # Go thru the keys in the same order as for the headline row
        <td><a href="{{link_url}}" alt="See details">{{displaydata[i][k]}}</a></td>
        % end   # Usual python indention to structure code does not work in .tpl files - "end" is used instead to end a block
     </tr>
     % end
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`

Comment: it worked! thanks man. Btw. what does the "scope" do in this case? is it kind of focusing next couple of lines or?

Comment: Well explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_scope.asp
Please, mark as solved :)